# Evaluation of $\int (r^2-x^2) dx$

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

I am learning how to approximate the volume of a sphere with integrals. I am confused on how $(1/3)x^3$ became $(1/3)r^3$, and why this being an even function allows you to pull a $2$ out front. Please help, many thanks

[image]

Comment: Substitute $r$ instead of $x$.

Comment: At first upper bound $\color{red}{minus}$ the second lower bound!

Comment: $$\left(r^2x-\dfrac13x^3\right)_0^r=\left(r^2\times r-\dfrac13(r)^3\right)-\left(r^2\times0-\dfrac13(0)^3\right)$$
final answer is $\dfrac43\pi r^3$.

Answer (score 0):

The volume is $$\int_{-r}^r \pi(r^2-x^2)dx=[\pi(r^2x-\tfrac{1}{3}x^3)]_{-r}^r=\tfrac{4\pi}{3}r^3.$$Since the integrand is even, we could alternatively write $$\int_{-r}^r \pi(r^2-x^2)dx=\int_0^r 2\pi(r^2-x^2)dx=[2\pi(r^2x-\tfrac{1}{3}x^3)]_0^r=\tfrac{4\pi}{3}r^3.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$F(x)|_{x=0}^{x=r}=F(r)-F(0)$$
(by definition of the left term)

$$f(-x)=f(x) \implies \int_{-r}^{r}f(x)\ dx=2\int_{0}^{r}f(x)\ dx$$
(consider the change of the lower bound too!)

Answer (score 0):

The volume of sphere is found by $$ V=2\int _0^r \pi  (r^2-x^2) dx= 2\pi \int _0^r   (r^2-x^2) dx$$

When you integrate you get  $$r^2x -(1/3) x^3$$ and when you evaluate from $0$ to $r$ you get $$(2/3) r^3$$

Thus the total volume will be $$V= (4/3) \pi r^3 $$